# javascript file cant see the other one

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've two javascript files, one of them I've vue code and in the other one I've got some data array and in it I created 'Feed' array, When I try to output simple string from that array console gives error and says 'Feed is not defined' any clues ?

```js
window.Feed = (function(){
  const stories = [
    {
      id:1,
      title:'Levani',
      text:'lorem ipsum',
      votes:0,
      postedAt: '3min ago',
      storyImage: 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=1'
    },]
    return {stories: stories};
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    stories: Feed.stories
  },
  methods:{
  }
});
```

```html
<img v-bind:src="stories[0].storyImage" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="data.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: What order are these scripts in your page?

Comment: @zero298 What do you mean ?

Comment: loading will matter here, you will need to ensure you first have referenced the file that has window.Feed in it.  First place I'd look is the html file where you are loading in your scripts. Make sure the window.Feed one is the first thing loaded

Comment: Is the second script running after the first one? Have you tried to access `window.Feed.stories` instead of `Feed.stories`? And finally, your `Feed` element is a function. You cannot access `window.Feed.stories` like that. You need to call the function, with something like this `window.Feed().stories`.

Comment: Show the HTML that adds these JavaScript files with the `<script>` tag.  The order matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call the IIFE:

```js
window.Feed = (function() {
  const stories = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Levani',
    text: 'lorem ipsum',
    votes: 0,
    postedAt: '3min ago',
    storyImage: 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=1'
  }, ]
  return {
    stories: stories
  };
}()); // You need to actually CALL the IIFE so add "()"

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    stories: Feed.stories
  },
  methods: {}
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <img v-bind:src="stories[0].storyImage" />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```